# Regex - extracting numbers from string in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

how to extract using SQL or PL/SQL all numbers from below strings?

[ 6d (1.5h; 31h)] x (5 to 7)

[ 1d (8h; 24h; 48.5h; 72h; 96h)] x (1 to 5)

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression and a correlated hierarchical query to get the values:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, value ) AS
SELECT 1, '[ 6d (1.5h; 31h)] x (5 to 7)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '[ 1d (8h; 24h; 48.5h; 72h; 96h)] x (1 to 5)' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id, COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.value, '\d+\.?\d*', 1, LEVEL )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.value, '\d+\.?\d*' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) n;
```

**Results**:

```
ID  COLUMN_VALUE
--- ------------
1   6
1   1.5
1   31
1   5
1   7
2   1
2   8
2   24
2   48.5
2   72
2   96
2   1
2   5
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\[\s*([0-9.]+)d\s*\((.*?)\)\]\s*x\s*\(([0-9.]+)\s*to\s*([0-9.]+)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS days,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\[\s*([0-9.]+)d\s*\((.*?)\)\]\s*x\s*\(([0-9.]+)\s*to\s*([0-9.]+)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ),
         '[^0-9.;]'
       )AS hours,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\[\s*([0-9.]+)d\s*\((.*?)\)\]\s*x\s*\(([0-9.]+)\s*to\s*([0-9.]+)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 3 ) AS x_from,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\[\s*([0-9.]+)d\s*\((.*?)\)\]\s*x\s*\(([0-9.]+)\s*to\s*([0-9.]+)\)', 1, 1, NULL, 4 ) AS x_to
FROM   table_name t;
```

**Results**:

```
DAYS HOURS           X_FROM X_TO
---- --------------- ------ ----
   6          1.5;31      5    7
   1 8;24;48.5;72;96      1    5
```

Comment: Thanks for answer... and if I want to create SQL thatw will devide string into 3 parts.(SQL return 3 columns) E.g. for [ 1d (8h; 24h; 48.5h; 72h; 96h)] x (1 to 5) it will be: column1 = 1, column2 = 8;24;48.5;72;96, column 3 = 1;5. How to do this?

Comment: @Cugar Updated - you would have been better putting your requirements into your question so that everyone knows what you are after when you asked the question rather than getting answers and then saying "actually, I want something else".

Comment: Thanks @MT0 for answer and suqestion.

Answer (score 1):

You may derive all digits seperated by a delimiter(pipes in this case) by the contribution of *regexp_replace* as in the following way :

```
select regexp_replace('[ 6d (1.5h; 31h)] x (5 to 7)','[^0-9.]+','|') str from dual union all
select regexp_replace('[ 1d (8h; 24h; 48.5h; 72h; 96h)] x (1 to 5)','[^0-9.]+','|') from dual;

STR
------------------
|6|1.5|31|5|7|
|1|8|24|48.5|72|96|1|5|
```

Comment: Did you mean to treat 48.5 as two separate numbers?

Comment: @AlexPoole ooh, thanks Alex, fixed by using ".\"

Comment: Hmm, it's fixed by including just the period; what is the backslash doing? (Also have to hope there won't be any other periods in the string, that aren't decimal separators!)